# What happens if I use git pull (merge) and squash my commit into master?

Tags: git, merge, squash

I'm unsure if this strategy is causing us more issues than it's worth. Let's use this as an example (pulled from git docs).

```
    A---B---C---D---E origin/master
        \     
         X---Y--- feature/branch
```

I've created a feature/branch of origin/master at commit B. I've committed X and Y locally. C, D, and E have been committed to origin by other developers. I then use `git pull origin master` to pull down latest changes from master into my feature/branch.

```
    A---B---C---D---E origin/master
        \            \
         X---Y--------M feature/branch
```

This appears to take CDE and creates a merge commit in my feature branch M. I then squash my feature branch creating commit Z and push it into origin.

```
    A---B---C---D---E       origin/master
        \            \     /
         X---Y--------M---Z feature/branch
```

It's possible I'm misunderstanding the `pull merge`.

Does origin now contain A,B,C twice?

Should we use rebase instead?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have no "feature branch". You are working directly on master.

Comment: And what does "squash" mean to you? Show the command by which you obtained `I` and the command by which you "push it into origin". In fact it would help if you showed all your commands.

Comment: "Does origin now contain A,B,C twice?" How can you be in doubt. Just `git fetch` and look at it for yourself.

Comment: And finally: what's the question? Your personal misconceptions seem to run very deep, and your work habits are a bit curious, but apart from that, nothing particularly interesting or surprising is happening here.

Comment: Matt, you're correct I pulled down master and commit directly into it in this example however I mention it like a feature branch. Sorry for the confusions.
Squash command - `git merge --squash`
Thank you, I will try git fetch to see what it looks like.
I guess the question is, should we use rebase instead?

Comment: `git merge --squash` _what?_ Having pulled to get H there is nothing more to merge. Or to squash. Your results (though not your working method) are totally normal up to H. After that point I can't make sense of your narrative.

Comment: Yes, git merge squash is an option when merging feature branches. https://www.git-tower.com/learn/media/pages/git/faq/git-squash/2675062452-1636925051/merge-vs-merge-with-squash.png

Comment: But you have no feature branch. And you cannot remerge what you already merged. Merely saying `git merge` when master is at H would do nothing.

Comment: I think the OP is asking or trying to understand the downstream effects of multiple feature branches being squashed (`git merge --squash`) into master and then merging master into future feature branches.  Does the continual squashing of feature branches into master and merging them into new feature branches present any long term concerns.

Comment: @matt I updated the drawings to be more like what I'm explaining and less a copy of the git docs. I hope that helps.

Comment: Then the answer is no it doesn't.  As long as you abandon the branch after squashing it into master, then aside from the loss of history there is no problem. But that is not what the diagrams show.

Comment: I still don't understand how you got Z. What branch were you on and what did you say? Show a complete record of complete commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: For the purposes of this answer, let's assume you have a local branch named `master` which is equivalent to `origin/master`, and another local branch named `feature` which is equivalent to `feature/branch`.

I believe your question is arising from the fact that your third graph is incorrect. Given your second graph as is:

```
    A---B---C---D---E (master)
        \            \
         X---Y--------M (feature)
```

If you then wish to squash `feature` onto `master` the resulting graph would be:

```
A---B---C---D---E---Z (master)
```

In this case commit `Z` would contain all of the changes from both commit `X` and `Y`, and also `M` if there were any changes in the merge commit.

If you had elected to rebase `feature` onto `master` instead of merging (in your case using pull), the graph would look like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E (master)---X'---Y' (feature)
```

Where `X'` and `Y'` represent the re-written commits of `X` and `Y`. If you then squashed those two commits down into one, you would be in the same place as the squash merge. (And then you would merge `feature` into `master` to get `master` up to date.)

> Does origin now contain A,B,C twice?

Assuming you push `master` to `origin`, in neither of these cases would origin (master) now contain A,B,C twice.

That being said, perhaps you conceptually had it backwards because it looks like your graph actually attempted to squash `master` onto `feature`. Had you done that, since `master` was already merged into `feature`, that subsequent squash merge would have had no effect meaning `Z` would not even have been created. However, had you *not* merged `master` into `feature` first, and then squash merged `master` onto `feature`, perhaps you would have gotten closer to what you were thinking, since the graph would look like this:

```
    A---B---C---D---E (master)
        \     
         X---Y---Z (feature)
```

And now `Z` would contain the changes from `C`,`D`, and `E` as you proposed. Then merging that back into `master` would look something like this:

```
    A---B---C---D---E---M (master)
        \              /
         X---Y--------Z (feature)
```

In that case `Z` is a pointless commit which you didn't need, and essentially the *changes* of the 3 commits are there twice. (Similar to when you cherry-pick commits onto other branches and then merge them back in later.)

For your last question:

> Should we use rebase instead?

It you're comparing merge vs rebase vs squash, it partially comes down to what you wish your graph to look like, but perhaps more importantly which information you wish to retain long term:

1. Squash has the least amount of information retention. It will contain the changes only. It does not retain any of the information about the authors, dates, developer's desired order and contents of commits, or original branching points at the time the development began.
2. Rebase retains the information about the authors, dates, and developer's desired order and contents of commits, but does not retain the original branching points at the time the development began.
3. Merge retains the information about the authors, dates, and the original branching points at the time the development began, but generally does not have the developer's *desired* order and contents of commits, but instead retains the *actual* order and contents of commits as they occurred.

Which one you choose is a matter of taste. For *feature branches* I personally prefer the rebase option, but only if the developers actually create meaningful commits that provide value on their own, and if multiple developers sharing a feature branch are comfortable with communicating force pushes and resetting their branches properly. If feature branch development doesn't meet that criteria I would prefer squash. For *long-lived shared branches* such as with Git Flow, I prefer merge (and --no-ff too). I would never rebase a long-lived shared branch.